# Extremities selectio

Tags: sql

I have table with hundreds of rows such as the following example
Input

```
Node-1 | Node-2 | ID
Strt1  | Bg2    | 567
Bf1    | Bg2    | 567
Hr     | Bf1    | 567
Strt2  | Al3    | 788
Al3    | Bo67   | 788
```

The output should find the last node per group ID. The starting node on each ID is known (in the example str1 and strt2).
The ouput should be something like that:
Output

```
Start-node | Last-node | ID
Strt1      | Hr        | 567
Strt2      | Bo67      | 788
```

NB: The number of rows in the inputs per ID is variable. In a programming language i think it could done via looping starting from starting point but i m not sure how it s possible with an sql.
Please advise how this can be achieved.

Comment: There is no "last" node in your table unless there exist one (or more) column(s) which provide the ordering you want.

Comment: Tell us your database

Comment: @Tim It's a list of graph edges that join up: Strt1 - Bg2 - Bf1 - Hr, and Strt2 - Al3 - Bo67. So I think the goal is to identify the ends of the edge chains given known starting nodes.

Comment: Hi, it s exactly how Rup described it and how to project that logic on sql regardless the data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `node_1` value that is never in `node_2` and the `node_2` that is never in `node_1`.  You can get these in separate rows using:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.node_2 = t.node_1
                 ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and
                        t2.node_1 = t.node_2
                 ) ;
```

Next, you want to put these on the same row.  For that, I would split this logic into two queries and use `join`:

```
select s.id, s.node_1, e.node_2
from (select t.*
      from t
      where not exists (select 1
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id = t.id and
                              t2.node_2 = t.node_1
                       ) 
     ) s join
     (select t.*
      from t
      where not exists (select 1
                        from t t2
                        where t2.id = t.id and
                              t2.node_1 = t.node_2
                       ) 
     ) e
     on s.id = e.id
```